# How to get list carts with magento API?

Tags: api, magento, soap, cart, magento2

I working on Magento with carts. I using SOAP to create cart and add products to it. but can i get list of carts. And how to active it.

In dashboard of magento admin, i see

```
Reports > Shopping Cart > Abandoned Carts
```

with list of carts is active. Can i get it?

Thank a lot, sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see how the query behind the report is generated, have a look at https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/83132783e0a6bed32c45e6d06df851865e668abc/app/code/Magento/Reports/Model/Resource/Quote/Collection.php#L54 - this is the code that forms the query. You can see the table fields it uses (e.g. checking if is_active, must be at least one item in cart, etc), then sorts by updated_at so oldest cart comes up first.

There is also a blog post at http://cyrillschumacher.com/2015/01/02/magento2---search-parameters-for-the-rest-api/ which describes (for the REST API) how to build a search. It is backed by the same data constructs as for SOAP.

You can use the end point http:///soap/default?wsdl&services=quoteCartRepositoryV1 to bring up the WSDL file.

Sorry, I don't have time right now to build up the SOAP request myself, but hopefully these pointers are useful to help you make some progress.